# Падает Android приложение при подключении Api VK

Tags: java, android-studio, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.
Создаю приложение, которое просто смогло подключиться бы к VK api для последующей обработки данных.

Вижу ошибку: `int java.lang.String.length()`, при попытке вызвать функцию возвращается `null`.

Я не пойму что именно не так. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
03-17 15:41:54.860 1863-4130/com.sir2100.vkapipic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1  
Process: com.sir2100.vkapipic, PID: 1863  

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference  
    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)  
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)  
    at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient$VKHTTPRequest.getQuery(VKHttpClient.java:253)  
    at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient$VKHTTPRequest.writeParams(VKHttpClient.java:208)  
    at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient$VKHTTPRequest.createConnection(VKHttpClient.java:313)  
    at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient.execute(VKHttpClient.java:167)  
    at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpOperation.start(VKHttpOperation.java:77)  
    at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient$2.run(VKHttpClient.java:145)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Сам код: (MainActivity.java)

```
package com.sir2100.vkapipic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken;
import com.vk.sdk.VKCallback;
import com.vk.sdk.VKSdk;
import com.vk.sdk.api.VKError;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VKSdk.login(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
package com.sir2100.vkapipic;

import com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken;
import com.vk.sdk.VKAccessTokenTracker;
import com.vk.sdk.VKSdk;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 17.03.2016.
 */
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
            if (newToken == null) {
                // VKAccessToken is invalid
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        VKSdk.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все стало нормально после обновления API вконтакте до версии 1.6.6.
3 дня мозголюбви из-за кривого API. 
Спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное ты забыл добавить в **versions.xml** информацию о ID приложения

```
<integer name="com_vk_sdk_AppId">YOUR_APP_ID</integer>
```

Comment: В файле **Strings.xml** добавлено
    <integer name="com_vk_sdk_AppId">5356832</integer>

Comment: Однако, то, что я его добавил сюда, не дало никакого результата. И я в **VKSDK_library** в **VKSdk** изменил переменную: **private static int sCurrentAppId = 5356832;**